# Store properties from object to array

Tags: arrays, angular, object

I have this JSON object:

```
{    "Aatrox": {
      "version": "10.23.1",
      "id": "Aatrox",
      "key": "266",
      "name": "Aatrox",
      "title": "la Espada de los Oscuros",
      "image": {
         "full": "Aatrox.png",
         "sprite": "champion0.png",
         "group": "champion",
         "x": 0,
         "y": 0,
         "w": 48,
         "h": 48
      }    },    "Ahri": {
      "version": "10.23.1",
      "id": "Ahri",
      "key": "103",
      "name": "Ahri",
      "title": "La Mujer Zorro de nueve Colas",
      "image": {
         "full": "Ahri.png",
         "sprite": "champion0.png",
         "group": "champion",
         "x": 48,
         "y": 0,
         "w": 48,
         "h": 48
      }    },    "Akali": {
      "version": "10.23.1",
      "id": "Akali",
      "key": "84",
      "name": "Akali",
      "title": "la Asesina Sigilosa",
      "image": {
         "full": "Akali.png",
         "sprite": "champion0.png",
         "group": "champion",
         "x": 96,
         "y": 0,
         "w": 48,
         "h": 48
         }    },    "Alistar": {
      "version": "10.23.1",
      "id": "Alistar",
      "key": "12",
      "name": "Alistar",
      "title": "El Minotauro",
      "image": {
         "full": "Alistar.png",
         "sprite": "champion0.png",
         "group": "champion",
         "x": 144,
         "y": 0,
         "w": 48,
         "h": 48
      }    } }
```

I need to store in a new array the values from keys "image.full" and "key" from every object.

How can I do that with typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it like this:

```js
// Extract the "data"
const { data } = { "type": "champion", "data": { "Aatrox": { "version": "10.23.1", "id": "Aatrox", "key": "266", "name": "Aatrox", "title": "la Espada de los Oscuros", "image": { "full": "Aatrox.png", "sprite": "champion0.png", "group": "champion", "x": 0, "y": 0, "w": 48, "h": 48 } }, "Ahri": { "version": "10.23.1", "id": "Ahri", "key": "103", "name": "Ahri", "title": "La Mujer Zorro de nueve Colas", "image": { "full": "Ahri.png", "sprite": "champion0.png", "group": "champion", "x": 48, "y": 0, "w": 48, "h": 48 } }, "Akali": { "version": "10.23.1", "id": "Akali", "key": "84", "name": "Akali", "title": "la Asesina Sigilosa", "image": { "full": "Akali.png", "sprite": "champion0.png", "group": "champion", "x": 96, "y": 0, "w": 48, "h": 48 } }, "Alistar": { "version": "10.23.1", "id": "Alistar", "key": "12", "name": "Alistar", "title": "El Minotauro", "image": { "full": "Alistar.png", "sprite": "champion0.png", "group": "champion", "x": 144, "y": 0, "w": 48, "h": 48 } } } };

const images = Object.entries(data).map(([, { key, image }]) => ({ key, image: image.full }));

console.log(images);
```

Comment: thank you. And what about "key" in the same const?

Comment: @Robert, have updated the code snippet above. Would like to know if it's the expected result? :)

Comment: VS code thows this error:
Property 'image' does not exist on type '{}'.
It's maybe because i get the real JSON from here:
http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.23.1/data/es_ES/champion.json
@KShewengger

Comment: @Robert, I see. Based on the JSON link you have sent, your list you want to extract is under data object property. So in your variable, you need to extract the "data" under that JSON to continue with the process. Have updated the snippet above. Hope it helps :)